# Comiple WebRTC Tizen

Tags: webrtc, samsung-mobile, chromium-embedded, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I am new to tizen app development, Any one tried to compile/deployed native code of WebRTC to Tizen. Because tizen 2.X will not support WebRTC. I tried lot ways to do. But it didn't worked to me, I cloned chromium webrtc source code. I don't know where to start. Kindly help me out for doing.

Answer (score 1):

After clone, you will have to build webrtc for environment (target_os,target_cpu) where you want to use webrtc libraries.

For compilation steps, you can refer - https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/

You can start any app development based on webrtc-native only after compiling webrtc successfully. So it should be your starting point.